Can I send Content Selection click data to a DE?
Salesforce Marketing Cloud, Einstein
I send an email to a client with 2 assets and I would like to save in a DE which image the client clicked on. For example: "Do you like movies or series more?" and the customer clicks on "movies" then it is recorded in a DE that customer X prefers movies.
If possible, can I send feedback so the customer knows that we recorded their click?

You can write an SQL query to retrieve from the dataviews the people who clicked on one link and those who clicked on the other link, and update it via an automation:
Select subscriberkey
from _click
where jobid = 'XXXX' and URL = 'XXXX'
Where jobId is the ID of the email sent job (you can find it in the reports) and the URL of the click.
You can add an alias attribute in the HTML tag in the code, which will help you recognize the links in your Email Studio reports.
